# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature, map

Tags: typescript

This code works:

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

const classCFromAOrB = (element: A | B): C => new C()

const a: A[] | B[] = [new A()]

const c: C[] = a.map(element => classCFromAOrB(element))
```

This code doesn't:

```
import { classA } from '../some'
import { classB } from './../some'

interface interfaceC {}

const render = (element: classA | classB): interfaceC => {
    return {}
}

interface ResultsScreenProps {
    resultsScreenPresented: boolean
    answers: classA[] | classB[]
    dismiss: SimpleFunc
}

const Screen: React.SFC<ResultsScreenProps> = (props) => {
    const array: classA[] | classB[] = props.answers
    const second: interfaceC[] = array.map(el => render(el)) // here is the error
    ...
}
```

On the line defining `second` I'm getting an error:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type '((callbackfn: (value: classA, index: number, array: classA[])
>   =>...' has no compatible call signatures.

What am I doing wrong?

The error is reproducible if classA looks like this:

```
class classA {
    anyArg: number

    constructor(anyArg: number) {
        this.anyArg = anyArg
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ResultsScreenProps`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, added declaration

Comment: What is `SimpleFunc`?

Comment: By the way I don't get this error; you might have transcribed something incorrectly. Could you post the actual code that's causing the issue?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I updated my question with type definition which should be broken. is it?

Comment: actually, first working example from my question stops to work, if you add any property inside of `classA` or `classB`

Comment: [You can't call methods which are union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294). Either redefine the type from `classA[] | classB[]` to `(classA | classB)[]`, or widen the value to that type before you call `map` on it.

Comment: @jcalz, awesome! redefining to `(classA | classB)[]` works. could you please explain more of this in an answer? especially, I'm wondering why it stops to work if I define anything in any of the classes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of TypeScript 4.3 this problem no longer occurs.  The pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42620) implemented support for calling `map()` on unions of array types.

[Playground link to code](https://tsplay.dev/N9JOom)

Even as early as TypeScript 3.3, there started to be more [support for calling unions of methods/functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), so the question and its answer below have been obsolete for a while.

---

Original answer for TypeScript 3.2 or below:

As I mentioned in the comments, [you can't call methods which are union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).  The call signature of `(classA[] | classB[])['map']` is

```
(
  <U>(
    callbackfn: (value: classA, index: number, array: classA[]) => U,
    thisArg?: any
  ) => U[]
) | (
  <U>(
    callbackfn: (value: classB, index: number, array: classB[]) => U,
    thisArg?: any
  ) => U[]
)
```

And the compiler gives up.  What you can do is widen your type from `(classA[] | classB[])` to `(classA | classB)[]`.  The former is "either this is an array of all `classA` elements, or it's an array of all `classB` elements", while the latter is "this is an array of elements, each of which is either a `classA` or a `classB`".  The former is more specific, since if you know `arr[0]` is a `classA`, then `arr[1]` will also be a `classA`... whereas the latter is less specific, since `arr[0]` might be a `classA` while `arr[1]` might be a `classB`.  One thing good about the latter is that `(classA | classB)[]['map']` has the single signature:

```
<U>(
  callbackfn: (value: classA | classB, index: number, array: (classA | classB)[]) => U, 
  thisArg?: any
) => U[]
```

and you *can* call that.

---

Your next question, "why does it stop working if I define anything in any of the classes" has to do with [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing).  In short, TypeScript thinks `classA` and `classB` are *the same type* if they have *the same members*.  This might be surprising since many other typed languages use [nominal typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202), where two types with different *names* are necessarily different types.  But TypeScript doesn't really work that way.

If `classA` and `classB` are both empty of properties, they will be seen as equivalent to `{}`, the empty type.  And `(classA[])|(classB[])` then reduces to `({}[])|({}[])` which is just `({}[])`.  And that isn't a union, so you can call its `map` method.

If you want `classA` to be seen as different from `classB` by the compiler, then you should [give them different properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible), at least until (and unless) TypeScript ever gets more first-class nominal typing.

---

Hope that helps you.  Good luck.