# Displaying an array received from Usestate hook with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to display an array of information using map that is received from the usestate hook. When writing the map function, I get a "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature." Error. If I create a function that returns the same information and call that function, I do not get the error.

```
    export default function Portfolio() {
      const [portfolioData, setPortfoloioData] = useState<IProject[] | []>([])

      useEffect(() => {
        const portfolio: IProject[] = getPortfolio()
        setPortfoloioData(portfolio)
      }, [])

//Function to display the map that works.
      const displayBlocks = (portfolioData: IProject[]): JSX.Element[] => {
        return portfolioData.map((item, index) =>
          <ProjectBlock key={index} project={item} index={index} />
        )
      }

      return (
        <div className='text-center pt-3'>
          <h1 className='pb-4'>Portfolio</h1>

//This works without error
          {displayBlocks(portfolioData)} 

//This shows the missing call signature error even though
//it is the same as what is returned by the displayBlocks function.
          {portfolioData.map((item, index) =>
            <ProjectBlock key={index} project={item} index={index} />
          )}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I would like to figure out how to display the information with a simple map within the return section without having to call another function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `IProject[] | []` as your state type? `IProject[]` can still be the type of an empty array, remove the union

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You error is this line

```
const [portfolioData, setPortfoloioData] = useState<IProject[] | []>([]);
```

`portfolioData` become union type of `IProject[] | []`. In this case it is useless and leads to error. Any variable of type `IProject[]` can hold empty array. So it is no need to create union of array of type `IProject` and array of type `any` (square braces without type are considered of type `any`).

To correct errors just do

```
const [portfolioData, setPortfoloioData] = useState<IProject[]>([]);
```

And if you want to dig into details why this happens, I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571733/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature-map) (it best describes the issue) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature/42487130).