# TypeScript compile error: Array.map(callback) expression is not callable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Following is a Node.js API written in Typescript,

```
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), async (req, res) => {
  var response = { }
  var list = []
  try {
    const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)

    var myfiles = req.files
    console.log("myfiles", myfiles);
    myfiles.map( function(item, index) {

                //return checkExisting(col, item)
    })
}}
```

and getting the following typescript error at the line `myfiles.map(function(item, index) {`

```
index.ts:77:13 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'File[] | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: File, index: number, array: File[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' are callable.
    Type 'File[]' has no call signatures.

77     myfiles.map( function(item, index) {
               ~~~
```

As I am completely new to Typescript, not sure, what is the problem, `myfiles.map(callback)` is a valid callable method on an array so why typescript reports not callbale.

Comment: Before the error line put: console.log (typeof myfiles) and type the result here

Comment: What if you add `async (req: {files: any[]}, res)`

Comment: the key would be to see what `checkExisting` does. Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573837/17447

Comment: @naveen Already disabled `checkExisting` and tried but same error. `checkExisting` a function

Comment: @AksJacoves It's a typescripts compile time error so `console.log` is not executed. I tried it. Moreover I see in the terminal `npm ERR! node-tutorial@1.0.0 prestart: `tsc`` and  `Failed at the node-tutorial@1.0.0 prestart script.`

Comment: @bTech: ok. could you please add that to the question. And whats the typeof as Aks Jacoves commented? comment the map altogether and try the log

Comment: @naveen As I said it's a compile time error so `console.log` is not executed.

Comment: Then use a catch after the try and put this log

Comment: @AksJacoves Please note, it's a typescript compiling error, so it's not able to compile further/beyond than that line of error

Comment: @naveen Yes, If I comment out .map() function then the compile is successful but the problem is why .map is not callable deteced by TypeScript as also in case of `arr.forEach`

Comment: What's the contents of your `package.json`? We can't really help you without knowing what packages you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that happens, but you can try this:

```
var myfiles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files))
```

It would look something like this:

```
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), async (req, res) => {
    var response = { }
    var list = []
    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)

        var myfiles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files))
        console.log("myfiles", myfiles);
        myfiles.map( function(item, index) {

            //return checkExisting(col, item)
        })
    }}
```